# Proftpd Install from rpmforge failed

Tags: ftp

When trying to install proftpd for centos 6 , I added the correct version of the rpmforge repo, I get the following error

```
Transaction Check Error:
file /usr/share/man/man3/MIME::Base64.3pm.gz conflicts between attempted installs of      perl-MIME-Base64-3.13
-1.el6.rf.x86_64 and perl-4:5.10.1-119.el6_1.1.x86_64
file /usr/share/man/man3/MIME::QuotedPrint.3pm.gz conflicts between attempted installs    of perl-MIME-Base64
-3.13-1.el6.rf.x86_64 and perl-4:5.10.1-119.el6_1.1.x86_64
```

I ran yum install proftpd which led me here.

I'm not entirely sure what is conflicting with the install. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install from [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) instead. It has proftpd and won't cause as many conflicts as RF.
and here's [a link to setup EPEL on your machine](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F)
Basically: "rpm -Uvh http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/Fedora/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm"

PS. Probably best to move this question to serverfault.com instead